authorize all requests from auth microservice + Keycloak
I have a spring boot application (spring boot version 2.6.8) which works along with keycloak.
The current spring boot application consists of all the rest api's along with the security/Auth filters to validate token with Keycloak. Now I want to separate this auth part from the this application (resource server) as auth microservice, so as the responsibility of validating the tokens shifts to this auth microservice and the resource server which deals with business api's.
Can i go with this approach ?. How will all the requests coming to resource server call the auth service (new service) to validate the tokens.
Thanks.

This is a bad idea. This new service will introduce latency and will need to be very tightly coupled to the existing one (bi-directional coupling between modules is a smell for misconception).

The idea of doing this was because i wanted to upgrade spring boot to 3 and because keycloak support for spring boot 3 is no more there i wanted to keep it as a separate service ,then i will be able to upgrade the resource server atleast.
